# Create table with partition using Laravel Schema Builder

Tags: mysql, laravel-4

Well, I am kinda new to Laravel community and was just wondering, would it possible to create a table with partition using Laravel 4 Schema Builder? If yes, can anyone please provide a small snippet.

Thanks!

Comment: No, there is no way to do this using `Laravel Schema BUilder`.

Comment: Well, I thought so, since I did not see in documentation. Anyways, thanks, I will put a short alternative answer to this question when I figure it out on my side :)

Answer (score 0):

well since now answer here, there is another answer advice using `DB::unprepared('create table ......');` inside the migration files
please [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39629347/how-to-implement-partition-in-laravel-database-migration)

beside there is bit of a trick here in collection using `partition() helper` [check here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-partition)