# How to implement partition in laravel database migration

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Using Laravel 5.3 how can I implement partition. Following is the mysql table structure I'm trying to add in migration.

```
CREATE TABLE `settings` (
    `id` INT(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `client_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `key` VARCHAR(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `value` TEXT COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `created_at` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `updated_at` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY `settings_id_primary` (`client_id`, `id`),
    UNIQUE KEY `settings_key_unique` (`client_id`, `key`),
    KEY `settings_id_key` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci PARTITION BY KEY (`client_id`) PARTITIONS 50;
```

Below is what I tried so far, but this is only adding columns & keys.

```
    Schema::create('settings', function(Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('id'); // I can't use increments, because throwing an error when I try to add primary key below
        $table->integer('client_id');
        $table->string('key');
        $table->text('value');
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->primary(['client_id', 'id']);
        $table->unique(['client_id', 'key']);
    });
```

How can I do the partition? If there migration doesn't support partition. Is there way I can dump the whole SQL query in the migration and run.

Comment: No, there is no way to do this using Laravel Schema BUilder

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it is help to you,

```
      Schema::create('settings', function(Blueprint $table) {
         $table-> increments('id');
         $table->integer('client_id')->primary();
         $table->string('key');
         $table->text('value');
         $table->timestamps();

         $table->unique(['client_id', 'key']);
       });
```

or

```
      Schema::create('settings', function(Blueprint $table) {
         $table-> increments('id');
         $table->integer('client_id');
         $table->string('key');
         $table->text('value');
         $table->timestamps();

         $table->primary('client_id');
         $table->unique(['client_id', 'key']);
       });
```

I searched everywhere, i can't solution find for partition.
  But,

My suggestion use, below unprepared into the migration file functions of **up** and **down** function

```
DB::unprepared()
```

in migration to run your SQL query with partition.

like,

```
DB::unprepared('create table....')
```

Comment: Where is the partition?

Comment: Please use unprepared or raw of DB. it maybe helpful to you.

Comment: @SauminiNavaratnam If it is work, then accept it.. Others will get knowledge on it.

Answer (score 2):

There's now a Composer package for this called brokenice/laravel-mysql-partition:

https://packagist.org/packages/brokenice

Here's a sample right from the docs:

```php
// You use their extended Schema class:
use Brokenice\LaravelMysqlPartition\Schema\Schema;
// You might also need this (I didn't need it for partitioning by hash):
use Brokenice\LaravelMysqlPartition\Models\Partition;

// I omitted class and method definition boilerplate...

// Create a table as you would normally:
Schema::create('partitioned', static function (Blueprint $table) {
    // ...
});
    
// Now partition it (it will run an ALTER TABLE query):
Schema::partitionByList(
    'partitioned', 
    'id',
    [
        new Partition('server_east', Partition::LIST_TYPE, [1,43,65,12,56,73]),
        new Partition('server_west', Partition::LIST_TYPE, [534,6422,196,956,22])
    ]
);
```