# Partition query in laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, partition

I have large amount of data stored in database and doing partitioning for that.
I am using Laravel for development.

I am getting problem for writing queries in Laravel with partitioning.
e.g. `SELECT * FROM employees PARTITION (p1);`
If I want to write this query, what will be the way to write this in Laravel.

Any help would be deeply appreciated. Thank You!

Comment: what you tried? any sample code?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39629347/how-to-implement-partition-in-laravel-database-migration

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement partition in laravel database migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39629347/how-to-implement-partition-in-laravel-database-migration)

Answer (score 0):

You can possibly achieve this with RAW Queries. The [Laravel Database Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/database#running-queries) has examples on this.

So try something like this:

```
$employees = DB::select("SELECT * FROM employees PARTITION (p1)");
dd($$employees);
```

Comment: I tried with this.
$results = eMaster::select( eMaster::raw("SELECT * FROM m_employee_b PARTITION (p2)") );

Comment: Does this raw queries affect query execution time?

Comment: Does this return any results though? 

I think the DB class in Laravel has some performance advantage over Eloquent. In your case though, I think the performance issues lies with your database due to the large amounts of data. If your partitions are setup correctly, and have improved the performance of your select queries then the above query should be fine.

Comment: $results = DB::select( DB::raw("SELECT * FROM m_employee_b PARTITION (p2)") );
Above query giving proper result. But I want to use Eloquent. Please help.